# USB manual mount problem in VMWare

Tags: usb, mount, vmware

So, I'm trying to disable automount and manually mount my usb flash drive for a project but running into a dead end here.  The drive is a 16 gig USB with a single FAT32 partition and works fine.  With automount enabled the drive appears in Ubuntu Desktop and I can access files with no problem.

I am disabling automount in Ubuntu by going through `dconf-editor`, browsing to `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling` and unchecking `automount` and `automount-open`.

Now, when I connect the drive [Player->Removable Devices->USB Drive->Connect] and run lsusb I can see the drive:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
```

and when I `check dmesg | tail -n 10` I can also see that it is assigned to sdb correctly:

```
[ 3339.962790] scsi 35:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler SE9 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 3339.965716] sd 35:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3339.968514] sd 35:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Yet when I run `fdisk -l` the sdb drive still won't appear:

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type    
/dev/sda1  *        2048 33554431 33552384  16G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       33556478 41940991  8384514   4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       33556480 41940991  8384512   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm at a loss at this point.  I'm thinking this has something to do with VMWare but not sure what to try from here.  The device works fine both in Windows and in the VM-Ubuntu when using auto-mount so I'm not sure what's preventing it from attaching to sdb1 when attempting to manual mount.

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb -- unit s print free  

Model: Kingston DataTraveler SE9 (scsi)   
Disk /dev/sdb: 30481152s  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B   
Partition Table: loop  
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Flags    
1      0s 30481151s  30481152s  fat32

$ udevadm info /dev/sdb
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host34/target34:0:0/34:0:0:0/block/sdb  
N: sdb  
S: disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_SE9_0060E049DF75EBB1D0002D49-0:0  
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0  
S: disk/by-uuid/8094-DE3A  
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_SE9_0060E049DF75EBB1D0002D49-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-uuid/8094-DE3A  
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb  
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/host34/target34:0:0/34:0:0:0/block/sdb  
E: DEVTYPE=disk  
E: ID_BUS=usb  
E: ID_DRIVE_THUMB=1  
E: ID_FS_TYPE=vfat  
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem  
E: ID_FS_UUID=8094-DE3A  
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=8094-DE3A  
E: ID_FS_VERSION=FAT32  
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0  
E: ID_MODEL=DataTraveler_SE9  
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=DataTraveler\x20SE9  
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6545  
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0  
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_03_00_0-usb-0_2_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0  
E: ID_REVISION=PMAP  
E: ID_SERIAL=Kingston_DataTraveler_SE9_0060E049DF75EBB1D0002D49-0:0  
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0060E049DF75EBB1D0002D49  
E: ID_TYPE=disk  
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage  
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:  
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00  
E: ID_VENDOR=Kingston  
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Kingston  
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0930  
E: MAJOR=8  
E: MINOR=16  
E: SUBSYSTEM=block  
E: TAGS=:systemd:  
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=234006460
```

Comment: What does `sudo lsblk` say?

Comment: >Gives me this:

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   16G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

(Sorry, don't know how to format text on this forum)

Comment: Please try `sudo parted /dev/sdb -- unit s print free` and post the result, together with `udevadm info /dev/sdb`. Edit the question to post the results, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

Your drive appears to be unpartitioned, that is, there is a filesystem made directly on `/dev/sdb`. You may want to try to mount it with

```
sudo mount -o uid=$USERNAME,gid=$USERNAME,fmask=0133,dmask=0022 /dev/sdb /mnt
```